# Sending an alert after input validation without reloading page

Tags: ajax, grails

I am validating the input of a form using grails validation for domain classes. I can differenciate between valid and invalid inputs, but the problem i cant get solved is that i want to show the missing/invalid inputs at the page without reloading it.

I wanted to use submitToRemote as shown in the example:

```
<g:form action="show">
        Login: <input name="login" type="text"></input>
        <g:submitToRemote update="updateMe" />
</g:form>
<div id="updateMe">this div is updated by the form</div>
```

Not sure if this really is the way i should go, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use submitToRemote element's `before` parameter to call a Javascript method which performs validation (and updates the page with any errors) asynchronously.  I think that method would need to return false if there were any errors, otherwise return true.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an action in javascript, looking something like this (if you'd use jQuery):

```
$('#id_of_form').submit(function() {

   var login = $('input[name="login"]').val()
   if(login.length == 0) {
         // Show some error, about an empty login
         $('#updateMe').text('Empty login is not allowed')
         return false; // will prevent submitting the form
   }

   return true; // Will allow submitting the form 
})
```

Untested, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

We move all the form to template and re-render it completely in Ajax, like:

**_myForm.gsp**:

```
<div id="userForm">

<!-- You can even add error list: -->
<g:hasErrors bean="${user}">
    <div class="errors">
      <grid:renderErrors bean="${user}"/>
    </div>
</g:hasErrors>

<g:form action="ajaxLogin">
        Login: <g:textField name="login" type="text" value="${user.login}"
          class="${hasErrors(bean: user, field: 'login', 'errors')}" />
        <g:submitToRemote update="userForm" />
</g:form>
</div>
```

**controller**:

```
def ajaxLogin = {
    User user = new User(params)
    if (!user.save()) {
        // validation errors get rendered here
        render template: 'myForm', model: [user : user]
    } else {
        render template: 'nextStep', model: [user : user, whatever: whatever]
    }
}
```

User has the impression that the form remained the same.

Though, for user login, I'd recommend that you use SpringSecurity plugin and not repeat it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I think this is going into the right direction, but when i reload the form template completely, the input text (in your example -> the user) will be gone. 

I thought about reloading another template, but it doenst seem to work with this

render template: 'myFormErrors', model: [user : user]

The template _myFormErrors just loads, but nothing else.

Comment: Does `user` variable in the ajax action get `login` field assigned?